# If-Then-Else Loop in SAS keeps producing one wrong output

Tags: loops, if-statement, sas

I'm trying to create a loop that will tell me if a patient is hypertensive or not by the conditions of if the patient is female and the SBP is greater than 138 or their DBP is greater than 88 and for males if their SBP is greater than 140 or their DBP is greater than 90. For some reason my loop keeps leaving out the M 142 82 patient which should be Yes but it keeps listing it as No.

```
title "Hypertensive Patients";
proc report data=learn.bloodpressure;
  column Gender SBP DBP Hypertensive;
  define Gender / Group width=6;
  define SBP / display width=5;
  define DBP / display width=5;
  define Hypertensive / computed "Hypertensive?" width=13;
  compute Hypertensive / character length=3;

  if Gender = 'F' and SBP gt 138 or DBP gt 88 then Hypertensive = 'Yes';
  else Hypertensive='No';
  if Gender = 'M' and SBP gt 140 or DBP gt 90 then Hypertensive = 'Yes';
  else Hypertensive = 'No';

  endcomp;
run;
quit;
```

`Hypertensive Patients
Gender  SBP DBP Hypertensive?
F   110 62  No
    120 70  No
    138 88  No
    132 76  No
M   144 90  Yes
    130 80  No
    142 82  No
    150 96  Yes`

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: You code("if Gender = 'M' and
SBP gt 140 or DBP gt 90") are different from your explain ("for males if their SBP is greater tha 140 and their DBP is greater than 90")

Comment: Sorry! That was a typo. It is supposed to be or.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use brackets in your conditional logic because `and` binds tighter than `or`, i.e. `and` logic is worked out before `or` logic. So at the moment, using brackets, your code would be seen as:

```
if (Gender = 'F' and SBP gt 138) or DBP gt 88
then Hypertensive = 'Yes';
else Hypertensive='No';
if (Gender = 'M' and
SBP gt 140) or DBP gt 90
then Hypertensive = 'Yes';
else Hypertensive = 'No';
```

Try adding some brackets as follows:

```
if Gender = 'F' and (SBP gt 138 or DBP gt 88)
then Hypertensive = 'Yes';
else Hypertensive='No';
if Gender = 'M' and
(SBP gt 140 or DBP gt 90)
then Hypertensive = 'Yes';
else Hypertensive = 'No';
```

This way the `or` logic will be worked out before applying the `and` logic, which could make a difference to your results.